# get ParentNodeName from PivotCell in a Pivottable

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I face issues with the following UseCase.
When the user clicks on a PivotCell item, I would later on want to know the ParentNode of this element.

You can see in the screenshot that "Gases" is selected, so now I would like to get the value "Inventory" since it is the Parent node of that element.

[image]

I have this so far, used that to get the indentLevel, but I cannot get the ParentNode value somehow.

```
Sub test()
    Dim sSelection As String
    Dim sPivotName As String: sPivotName = "PT_L1"
    Call declareVariables
    For Each OneCell In Selection
        sSelection = OneCell
    Next OneCell

    Dim oPivot As PivotTable
    Set oPivot = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping").PivotTables(sPivotName)

    Set oPivotField = oPivot.PivotFields("Account Caption")
    For Each pvtfld In oPivotField.DataRange
        If pvtfld.Cells = sSelection Then
            Debug.Print oPivotField.DataRange.PivotCell.ParentField
        End If
        'Debug.Print pvtfld.IndentLevel

    Next pvtfld
End Sub
```

*Edit*: I think it cannot determine the parentNode because I am within another PivotField in the loop?

*Edit (Markup Table):*

```
| Account Caption          | Account Type | L2     | L3                        |
|--------------------------|--------------|--------|---------------------------|
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Cash at bank and in hand | BS           | Assets | Cash and cash equivalents |
| Gases                    | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Gases                    | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Gases                    | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Gases                    | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Gases                    | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Gases                    | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Gases                    | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Gases                    | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Gases                    | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Gases                    | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Gases                    | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Gases                    | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Gases                    | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Gases                    | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Gases                    | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Resale                   | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Resale                   | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Resale                   | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Resale                   | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Spares                   | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Spares                   | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Spares                   | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
| Spares                   | BS           | Assets | Inventory                 |
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you use a markdown table generator to share a small sample of data complete with headers? You paste the table into generator then copy the generator output into question between code tags.

Comment: At present I don't know which column is Account Caption - is it the one containing _gases_ etc ?

Comment: yes, it's the one containing gases.

Comment: edited my post and pasted the markup table. The parent of "Account Caption" would be "L3".

Comment: Are there also data values in the VALUES area of pivot?

Comment: no - only those 4 fields in the Row-Section of the PivotTable. There is no other filter, columns or values in the pivot-customizing.

Comment: Will the layout be the same as shown? I.e. row range is one column with indent levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the following is a bit clunky and WIP. Assuming layout as shown you could loop back through rows until indent level changes and then take the cell value at that point.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim sPivotName As String: sPivotName = "PT_L1"
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mapping")
    Dim oPivot As PivotTable: Set oPivot = ws.PivotTables(sPivotName)

    Dim topRow As Long, currentRow As Long, startLevel As Long, currentColumn As Long
    Dim cross As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    cross = Intersect(Selection, oPivot.RowRange)
    On Error GoTo 0

    topRow = oPivot.TableRange1.Row + 1
    currentRow = Selection.Row
    currentColumn = Selection.Column
    startLevel = Selection.IndentLevel

    With ws

        If currentRow > topRow And Not IsEmpty(cross) Then

            Do
                currentRow = currentRow - 1
            Loop While .Cells(currentRow, currentColumn).IndentLevel = startLevel And currentRow >= topRow

        End If

        If .Cells(currentRow, currentColumn).IndentLevel < startLevel Then
            Debug.Print .Cells(currentRow, currentColumn).Value
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: that one worked! I tried the same with looping back. I took the row-value from the selection and then looped back like "for i = .cells.pivotfield.row to 6 step -1", but I did not know how to get the text value after each itereation with the "i".